# What is the best way to produce the report in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, reporting-services

Can anyone advise me how to create the report in a asp.net core program. I would like to export the report as excel, pdf and word. What is the best way to produce the report in asp.net core? I am looking for advise from expertise

Comment: The best way is the one that fits your needs and meets optimal performance requirements.

Comment: @LazZiya RDLC, Crystalor SSRS reports don't work in ASP .Net Core. My question is which reporting tool do you suggest to use for reporting in ASP .Net Core?

Answer (score 5):

I am doing a project in Asp.Net Core 2.1. I used Rotativa.AspNetCore for reporting feature. It is free you can get from the NUGET just install that and thats it.

It Convert the view to pdf. You just pass your model to view and create html table or what you want and along with css. This library convert your view to PDF.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Registration(int id)
{
    var reg = await _context.Registrations
        .Include(x => x.Property.Block)
        .Include(x => x.Property.Phase)
        .Include(x => x.Property.Street)
        .Include(x => x.Nomines)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    var report = new ViewAsPdf("Registration")
    {
        PageMargins = { Left = 5, Bottom = 5, Right = 5, Top = 5 },
        Model = reg
    };
    return report;
}
```

Here is the html for that view. I remove long html stuff but you can check my code.

```
<div class="row">
        <h1 class="report-heading text-center">Registration Form</h1>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 report-label">Date:-</label>
                    <label class="col-xs-9 report-field">@(Model.DateTime?.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 report-label">Form #</label>
                    <label class="col-xs-8 report-field">@(Model.FormNo)</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                    <label class="col-xs-5 report-label">Plot/House #</label>
                    <label class="col-xs-7 report-field">@(Model?.Property?.No)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 report-label">Street:-</label>
                    <label class="col-xs-9 report-field">@(Model?.Property?.Street?.Name)</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 report-label">Marla:-</label>
                    <label class="col-xs-9 report-field">@(Model?.Property?.Marla)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 report-label">Sqft:- </label>
                    <label class="col-xs-9 report-field">@(Model?.Property?.Sqft)</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 report-label">Block:-</label>
                    <label class="col-xs-9 report-field">@(Model?.Property?.Block?.Name)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 report-label">Phase:-</label>
                    <label class="col-xs-9 report-field">@(Model?.Property?.Phase?.Name)</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And i you want to export that view to excel then you just need to add header before returning the view. It is a sample.

```
public ActionResult Export()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    return View();
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Suggest some reporting tools like crystal, rdlc. we have so many reports. Need a tools to extend my development. also Rotativa.AspNetCore isn't free.

Comment: It is reporting tool. But it is not like that you create a report like rdlc and crystal report. It create your view to pdf just like rdlc do. If you need that then you have to pay for that. And there are no of reporting tools which need subscription.

Comment: Without using paid reporting tools, Is there any other solution?

Comment: No. I did not know about any reporting tool which is free for Asp.Net core. This is the solution which i give you. Write you html and your report is ready.

Comment: I understand but, how can I use the designer? There is only xml codes

Comment: Asp.Net core not support rdlc. May be Microsoft add support for that. But if you are familiar with HTML and css and also model binding with Asp.Net mvc you can do this. It is very easy you do not have to create a report or something just add view with html and css. And after that i mentioned in the code how to return pdf from controller.

Comment: I'm using jsreport by using HTML and CSS. It would be easier If I could use any designer

Comment: It has issues on mac, has anyone used Rotativa on mac here ?

Comment: If anyone want to add the RDLC report to .NET Core project so here is the link. http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the format of the report. If it is a tabular format report then you might consider [html DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) which comes with Pdf, word, excel and Print option out of the box.

Check the multi-level header option here which is usually needed for reports: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create pdf/excel/word using rdlc report I recommend you can use AspNetCore.Reporting library. This is open source and comes as a nuget package. you can integrate this in your .NET Core API or .NET Core Azure function. You can generate a byte array convert it to base 64 string and retrieve that to your client side. I have written a sample report generation project which you can find it in [here](http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects).

Comment: Not a good option. This library has multiple issues and there is no answer/update by the developer on github page. Highly recommend not to use this library else your life will be hell.

Comment: @Waleed Naveed Thanks! Was thinking about using it cause I saw it in a youtube video but it seems like a sketchy NuGet package and the website isn't even up. Do you happen to have a tool you use?

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress seems to have a free reporting tool.  I have not used it and don't know how effective it is or if it suits your needs, but probably worth looking at.

https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2020/06/09/blazor-ui-components-official-release-with-new-controls-amp-features-and-blazor-reports-available-in-v20-1.aspx