# Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.ParseChildrenAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, runtime-error, visual-studio-2019

My ASP.NET MVC Core 3.0 application was running fine,
Suddenly facing an error when I run the application.

> Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.ParseChildrenAttribute'
> from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

I'm using IIS Express and Visual Studio 2019.
Error screenshot attached:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CrystalReport in the asp.net core project? Currently .net core does not support System.Web.UI.ParseChildrenAttribute.

Refer to:

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13054071/is-crystal-report-support-net-core-31.html

[ParseChildrenAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.parsechildrenattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Maybe you can use dotnet Report，With the dotnet report generator, end users can decide which fields to add to the report, how to format, etc. through a very friendly and intuitive report wizard. All this is done inside your application, so there is no need to export data or run other programs：

https://dotnetreport.com/kb/docs/getting-started/introduction/

You can also refer to some of the reporting tools mentioned in this post:

[What is the best way to produce the report in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842325/what-is-the-best-way-to-produce-the-report-in-asp-net-cor)e

Comment: Yes I'm trying to run crystal reports. That's mean we cannot run crystal reports in ASP.NET MVC core Application. 
Can you please suggest any other way for reporting.

Comment: Try my updated content.